# How do I toggle a cell class in a shiny DT datatable?

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, dt

Using Shiny and DT, I want to trigger an event for specific cells in a  datatable. Suppose I want the first column to turn red on hover. When I create the table I add a callback that registers a hover event on the td elements in the first column.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".red { background-color: red; }"))),
  DT::dataTableOutput("iris")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$iris <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(iris, callback = JS("
table.column(0).nodes().to$().hover(function(){$(this).toggleClass('red');});
")))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

From the javascript console if I run the identical code it works :

```
table=$('#DataTables_Table_0').DataTable()
table.column(0).nodes().to$().hover(function(){$(this).toggleClass('red');});
```

Why doesn't this work in the datatable callback? What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when you see this sort of behaviour, it suggests a timing issue. The callback is being called back before the table is fully rendered, the the columns you want to operate on don't exist just quite yet.

Remove the `callback` option and use `options = list( drawCallback = JS(...) )` instead.

```
DT::datatable(
  iris,
  options = list(
    drawCallback = JS('function() {this.api().table().column(0).nodes().to$().hover(function(){$(this).toggleClass("red")}) }')
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks Dean. (Two times in one week!)

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here are three solutions: `drawCallback`, `rowCallback`, and `table.on`. [drawCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) was given as the answer, above. 
[columnDefs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback) can be used to assign a class to a column, which makes it easy to use selectors. [rowCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback) is an alternative to drawCallback. And, last, events can be assigned using [on()](https://datatables.net/reference/event/) in the datatables API for mouse events, but you must manage both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead of jQuery's `hover()` convenience method. (I find this last solution perplexing because the documentation (1) does not have a second selector parameter *and* (2) mouse events are not listed in the [events API](https://datatables.net/reference/event/), but that's what works!)

*Important, only one of these is needed, not all three!* Personally, I like the `rowCallback` as the most concise.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".red { background-color: red; }"))),
  div(id='tbl1', DT::dataTableOutput("iris"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$iris <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(iris, 
                                                   options = list(drawCallback=JS("function() { this.api().table().column(0).nodes().to$().hover(function(){$(this).toggleClass('red');}); }"),
                                                                  rowCallback=JS("function(row) { $(row).children('.firstcol').hover(function(){$(this).toggleClass('red')}) }"),
                                                                  columnDefs=list(list(className='firstcol', targets=0))),
                                                    callback = JS("
 table.on('mouseenter', 'td.firstcol', function() { $(this).addClass('red'); });
 table.on('mouseleave', 'td.firstcol', function() { $(this).removeClass('red'); });
")))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```